# performance concern, Python vs C

Tags: python, c, python-imaging-library

I was using PIL to do image processing, and I tried to convert a color image into a grayscale one, so I wrote a Python function to do that, meanwhile I know PIL already provides a `convert` function to this.

But the version I wrote in Python takes about 2 seconds to finish the grayscaling, while PIL's convert almost instantly. So I read the PIL code, figured out that the algorithm I wrote is pretty much the same, but
PIL's `convert` is written in C or C++.

So is this the problem making the performance's different?

Comment: C is *much* faster than Python in terms of execution speed (in most cases). Something that would be of particular importance here would be looping (to iterate over the pixels) which is slow in python.

Comment: Generally, for CPython at least, processor intensive routines should be written in C or C++, and called as extension modules from Python if performance is a major concern

Comment: This has no relation with PIL at all, read about languages interpreted by virtual machines (commonly referred as interpreted languages, sometimes scripting languages) and languages interpreted by actual hardware (commonly referred as compiled languages).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, coding the same algorithm in Python and in C, the C implementation will be faster.  This is definitely true for the usual Python interpreter, known as CPython.  Another implementation, PyPy, uses a JIT, and so can achieve impressive speeds, sometimes as fast as a C implementation.  But running under CPython, the Python will be slower.

Comment: Just as @Charles said in the above comment, `processor intensive routines should be written in C or C++`, then why would we need Python? Just go ahead and  do all the jobs in C

Comment: Because not all programs are processor intensive, and even the ones that are, often you can use someone else's C code, by using libraries like numpy or PIL, as you have found.  Python offers improved programmer productivity, which can be a huge win.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do image processing, you can use

OpenCV(cv2), SimpleCV, NumPy, SciPy, Cython, Numba ...

OpenCV, SimpleCV SciPy have many image processing routines already.

NumPy can do operations on arrays in c speed.

If you want loops in Python, you can use Cython to compile your python code with static declaration into an external module.

Or you can use Numba to do JIT convert, it can convert your python code into machine binary code, and will give you near c speed.